# What is the ehome folder in C:\Windows for?

Tags: windows-vista, boot

On my Windows Vista partition, startup has been slow lately, so I went and did my usual spring clean.

One item I noticed in msconfig was called Microsoft(r) Windows(r) Operating System. Which surprised me, because it's not as if Windows would have the option to not let itself startup on startup.

It corresponds to the file path: C:\Windows\ehome\ehTray.exe .

Any idea what this is? And is it safe to disable it from auto starting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what it says about ehtray.exe:

> ehtray.exe is the tray
>   bar process for the Microsoft Media
>   Center. It gives you easy access to
>   the digital media manager. This is a
>   non-essential process

So it does not seem to be something suspicious.

Answer (score 2):

[Identify mystery start-up apps in XP and Vista](http://download.cnet.com/8301-2007_4-10069846-12.html)

> [**Microsoft Media Center Tray Applet**] it is used for viewing TV and other video. I also found out that it isn't essential and will start automatically when Media Center requires it, so the program doesn't really belong in my start-up list.